# Early descriptions of the Foundation Stone

Tags: history, tanach, beis-hamikdash

I am looking for early descriptions of the "Foundation Stone" (אבן שתיה) -- the huge flat rock now enclosed by the "Dome of the Rock," and believed by many Jewish scholars to have been the site of the Holy of Holies, as well as the place that Yaakov dreamed about the ladder to Heaven, and Avraham brought Yitzhok as an offering.  The [Mishna Yoma 5:3](http://emishnah.com/moed2/Yoma/5.pdf) and the Gemara at [Yoma 54a](http://halakhah.com/rst/moed/15b%20-%20Yoma%20-%2028a-61b.pdf) give detailed descriptions and discussions of the rock, as does Josephus and later rabbinic sources.  What sources from the First or Second Temple eras, if any, exist which describe the stone as it existed then (it is known that Crusaders greatly damaged the rock) and which the Mishna and later sources relied upon as proof that this rock was the center point of the Holy of Holies?

Comment: You have it backwards. The Mishna had a tradition that the Even Shetiya was the center of the Holy of Holies. It is our tradition that the rock the Muslims call the Foundation Stone is in fact the Even Shetiya.

Comment: @DoubleAA I thought that's what I said.  I want to know if the tradition has textual sources in Tanach, or if at least there are Biblical descriptions of such a flat rock that the Patriarchs, David and Solomon recognized as having special significance.

Comment: Which tradition?

Comment: @Scimonster I considered making that edit, but backed off because it might be discussed with that lettering in sources I've never seen....I probably should have left a comment about it, in retrospect.

Comment: How about the Zohar הזוהר הקדוש - ספר בראשית-פרשת נח -דף עב ע''א that saysהַאי הִיא אֶבֶן שְׁתִיָּה דְּאִיהִי נְקוּדָה חָדָא דְּכָל עָלְמָא. וְקָיְימָא עֲלָהּ קֹדֶשׁ הַקֳּדָשִׁים. If Rashbi wrote the Zohar, it would date from the end of the 2nd temple area.

Comment: Why isn’t the Mishnah a Second-Temple-era source?

Comment: @DonielF so you mean his question suggests that he doesn't think it is